# Does this PHP code cause memory leaking?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, fopen

I'm a newbie. I have this piece of code that need your help to check if it cause memory leak? The idea of this code is it check if the status.txt file not empty then its content will show in webpage, it also check readmore.txt if this file not empty, it will have a hyperlink to a file.
Here is the code, please help

```
$statusfile = "status.txt";
$handle = fopen($statusfile, "r");
$string = '';
while (!feof($handle)) { $string .= fgets($handle); }
fclose($handle);

$readmore_file_path = 'readmore.txt';
$handle2 = fopen($readmore_file_path, "r");
$string2 = '';
while (!feof($handle2)) { $string2 .= fgets($handle2); }
fclose($handle2);

$strTxt = 'SYSTEM STATUS<br>';

if ('' != $string)
{ 
   $strTxt .= $string;
   if ('' != $string2) { $strTxt .= '. <a href="readmore.txt"> More details</a>'; }
   $strTxt .= '<br>';   
   echo $strTxt;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think that this code is causing a memory leak? Nothing that is written in pure PHP should leak memory; if PHP code *does* leak memory, then it's a bug in PHP.

The first five lines of your code sample can be replaced with:

```
$statusfile = "status.txt";
$string = file_get_contents($statusfile);
```

Similarly, the next five lines can be replaced with:

```
$readmore_file_path = "readmore.txt";
$string2 = file_get_contents($readmore_file_path);
```

See:  [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

**EDIT:**

```
$status_file = "status.txt";
$readmore_file = "readmore.txt";

if (filesize($status_file) != 0) {
    echo "SYSTEM STATUS<br>";

    readfile($status_file);

    if (filesize($readmore_file) != 0) {
        echo ". <a href=\"readmore.txt\">More details</a>";
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that code cause memory leak. The RAM starts increasing every day after we had that code in place. Not sure if fopen() could cause leaking?

Comment: @KhaHoang: RAM usage is likely increasing because this code reads the entire contents of the two files into memory. Depending on how large the files are, this can be significant. It also sounds like the files are getting bigger as time progresses, meaning that more RAM is needed to read the file contents into memory. Consider rewriting it to not read the files into memory. See my edit.